# Is it possible to Upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 today?

Tags: server, upgrade, 10.04

I have an Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and my internet searches haven't provided a clear answer about whether it is possible for me to upgrade this webserver that is still in production on an intranet.

My understanding is that I must upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 then to 14.04 and so on.

If in fact it's possible and the sequential upgrades are necessary, I would like to find reliable guidance for this process.

Please advise,

Comment: Nope. Reinstall fresh and try to apply updates at least twice a decade 

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS had upgrade options available to it, until it's upgrade path to 12.04 LTS was EOL & thus gone.  [Ubuntu release upgrade tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) will check what releases are available, and limit themselves to those upgrades, but if you check https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release you'll note it will read 12.04 is **not** supported thus you're now too late.

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved with QA; and for desktop systems often use *unclean* install processes to ensure I go to a specific release; without need to restore backups or re-install user applications, data etc.  I often go backwards & forward in unusual steps, so *upgrade via re-install* is very possible with desktop systems, but it's not intended for server applications as all system directories get wiped prior to re-install, and server apps commonly store data/configs in those directories meaning data/setup is lost for server applications.  I suggest you take note of release & EOL notices in future

Comment: Read https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2015/04/30/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-end-of-life-reached-on-april-30-2015/ on 10.04's EOL, and [here for 12.04 which is what made *release-upgrade* path unavailable](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/).   From 10.04 (or 2010-April) it was pretty easy to count +5 years for EOL & further +2 years to know when *release-upgrade* path is gone even if you missed the notices  (*for planning purposes; the YEAR.MONTH format is there for a reason as businesses like to plan ahead*).

Comment: Its open source, a custom upgrade script can be made for any server, its question of time and money. The first thing I would do is make a disk image of the server to use as a backup and a test on another server with the same hardware.

Comment: (*my first comment included some clues in that regard; re: turtle's comment, but again there are many options as to how, the QA being your responsibility now anyway*)

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate of a almost 12 year old question as there are more virtualization tools available these days.